# How to deploy the Sql files to Dedicated Server with Azure Devops Pipeline CI/CD

Tags: entity-framework, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, dbcontext

I am working on Azure DevOps CI CD Pipelines. The project's Backend is Dotnet Core, Frontend is Angular 8 and for Database, we used Entity Framework code-first approach. I was able to add Front and back end in pipelines. Now I am stuck with database deployment. since I was also unable to find any dedicated article.

The project is consists of Multi Context and Multi-Project. [Reference folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4DQg.png)

At local we usually run this command to generate migration and it works fine.

> **Add-Migration -Context ABCCompanyContext AddCompanyTable**

Now, in Pipeline i have added the following command which I get from stackoverflow it self. but it didn't work. But from the error. it seems like I am really close

**Pipeline Command**

> dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef dotnet ef migrations script -i
> -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Migrations\migrate.sql --project **/ABC.Company.Data.csproj --startup-project **/ABC.Company.Api.csproj -i -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Migrations\migrate.sql

**Error Log**

> 2020-12-24T06:49:27.0265041Z ========================== Starting
> Command Output ===========================
> 2020-12-24T06:49:27.0688206Z ##[command]"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
> /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL
> "D:\a_temp\f3a33029-4f61-404f-9b64-c73c5296123a.cmd""
> 2020-12-24T06:49:32.9358440Z You can invoke the tool using the
> following command: dotnet-ef 2020-12-24T06:49:32.9359182Z Tool
> 'dotnet-ef' (version '5.0.1') was successfully installed.
> 2020-12-24T06:49:38.4701578Z System.IO.IOException: The filename,
> directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. :
> 'D:\a\1\s**\obj' 2020-12-24T06:49:38.4702878Z    at
> System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath, Byte[]
> securityDescriptor) 2020-12-24T06:49:38.4703503Z    at
> System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
> 2020-12-24T06:49:38.4704199Z    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Project.FromFile(String file,
> String buildExtensionsDir, String framework, String configuration,
> String runtime) 2020-12-24T06:49:38.4705029Z    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.RootCommand.Execute(String[] _)
> 2020-12-24T06:49:38.4705729Z    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(String[]
> args) 2020-12-24T06:49:38.4706399Z    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[]
> args) 2020-12-24T06:49:38.4707003Z    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
> 2020-12-24T06:49:38.4707626Z The filename, directory name, or volume
> label syntax is incorrect. : 'D:\a\1\s**\obj'
> 2020-12-24T06:49:38.6646502Z ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
> 2020-12-24T06:49:38.7627325Z ##[section]Finishing: Build EfCore
> Migrations

Comment: Hi @Harshdeep Singh, How are things going? Have you tried the suggestion in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please try it. Any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The error message,

> System.IO.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'D:\a\1\s\*\obj'

The path string contains the character '`*`'. Normally this character is not available in file name and folder name.

As the introduction from the docs about [**.NET Core CLI**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#common-options), the values of the options '**`--project`**' and '**`--startup-project`**' are the relative paths to the project folders.

According to my test, in the '**`dotnet ef`**' command, it seems does not support wildcard patterns.

- When I use wildcard patterns to set the path values, it always return the same error message.

> System.IO.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'D:\a\1\s\**\obj'

- However, when I directly provide the complete relative paths instead of using wildcard patterns, the error disappears.

So, I recommend you directly use the complete relative paths to the project folders.